# Как переслать ответ на сообщение из чата обратно пользователю?

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота на Python, с помощью библиотеки Telebot.

Написал бота, который пересылает фото от пользователя в нужную группу. Но не могу сделать так, чтобы ответ на пересланное сообщение в группе - улетал обратно пользователю.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.